# I am making a parametized markdown in Rstudio, and am having trouble changing the colors of the bar chart produced with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is the code I have:

```
a <- ggplot(euro.groups, aes(x = Group, y = average_emp)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = params$industry),
           stat = "identity",
           position = "dodge") + 
  ggtitle("% of Employment by Group") +
  xlab("Group") +
  ylab("% Employed in Industry") +
  scale_fill_manual("legend", values = c("EU" = "blue", "Eastern" = "red", 
                    "EFTA" = "green", "Other" = "black")) +
  theme_grey()
```

There will be four bars on the plot called. Can I assign them different colors by "Group"? Thank you!

Comment: Can you post an example of your data? Like `dput(euro.groups)` and `dput(params)`

Comment: don't use the $ notation inside the `aes()`. You probably need to join  euro.groups and params first